# Numbering duplicates record in mysql (2)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Table , (sequence_No.) Field is `null` :

```
ID        Name      age     sequence_No.
--        -----     ---     ------------
1         sara      20         
2         sara      20           
3         sara      20         
4         john      24         
5         john      24         
6         Hama      23
```

I want to Update it to this:

```
ID        Name      age     sequence_No.
--        -----     ---     ------------
1         sara      20         1
2         sara      20         2
3         sara      20         3
4         john      24         1
5         john      24         2
6         Hama      23         1
```

Which query can do that in `mysql`?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate `ROW_NUMBER()` using correlated subquery in mysql. The resulting table with sequential number will be join with the table itself and update the value of `sequence_No` using the generated numbers.

```
UPDATE  tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  A.ID, 
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    tableName c
                        WHERE   c.Name = a.Name AND
                                c.ID <= a.ID) AS sequence_No
            FROM    TableName a
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.sequence_No = b.sequence_No
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/567df/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID, Name, age, sequence_No
FROM
        (
            select  ID,
                    Name,
                    age,
                    @sum := if(@nme = Name AND @acct = age, @sum ,0) + 1 sequence_No,
                    @nme := Name,
                    @acct := age
            from    TableName,
                    (select @nme := '', @sum := 0, @acct := '') vars
            order   by  Name, age
        ) s
ORDER   BY ID
```

Or you may use

```
SELECT 
ID,
Name,
age,
( 
CASE Name 
WHEN @curType 
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := Name END
) + 1 AS sequence_No

FROM student, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY  ID,NAME;
```

this would work though i have not tested yet you can use the same to update your table